# Javascript Modular Passing data between functions

Tags: javascript

I am trying to pass data between functions in this way:

```
var mySample = {

    myFunction1: function(param1) {  

        alert(param1 + 'is here');

    },

    myFunction2: function() {  

        alert('need' + param1 + ' here')

    }

};
```

This is not being passed so my question is...have can I share data / variables above?

Comment: What exactly is the relation between `myFunction1` and `myFunction2`? What does `myFunction2` have to do with `myFunction1`?

Comment: I want to pass data from 1 to 2

Comment: Then `myFunction1` has to call `myFunction2` and pass the value to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are just functions, so they have no relationship to each other. However, if you're trying to call `myFunction1` first to set a value, then `myFunction2` to retrieve it, you can assign the `param1` value to a field:

```
var mySample = {
    myFunction1: function(param1) {  
        this._param1 = param1;
    },
    myFunction2: function() {  
        alert('need ' + this._param1 + ' here')
    }
};

mySample.function1("A");
mySample.function2();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    var mySample = {
        paramCache: null,

        myFunction1: function(param1) {  
            var self = this; //mySample

            alert(param1 + 'is here');
            self.paramCache = param1;

        },

        myFunction2: function() {  
            var self = this; //see above

            alert('need' + self.paramCache+ ' here')

        }
};
```

That would be 1 way to do it within an Object.
But that would require `myFunction1();`to be called BEFORE `myFunction2();`.

The `var self = this;` part might be useless in this case but I always do it, so .. yeah.. It's up to you.

EDIT: guess someone had the same Idea but was a split-second quicker :)